# PHP "filled" function parameters

Tags: php

The code below works and it is so clean:

```
<?php
    preg_match('/(bar)/', 'love hotel bar', $matches);
    print_r($matches);
```

As you can see before calling the function `$matches` is undefined, which normally should return an error... The function parameter is filled by value and it is accessible out scopes.

❌ Bad

```
<?php
$title = get_og_tag('title');
$description = get_og_tag('description');
echo $title; //My title
```

✅ Could be Good

```
<?php
get_og_tag($title, $description, $og_url, $og_image, $twitter_card);
echo $title; // [error] $title, $description, ..etc, undefined...
```

For the code's clarity cake **How to create functions like this?**

Comment: `$title = null` ?

Comment: Just assume the **function get_og_tag()** is autoloaded, but **$title** is not defined anywhere... :)

Comment: Absolutely! @0stone0 This is what I need, so putting `&` before the variable parameter is the key.. Thanks a lot! 